# xamarin cannot convert from system.nfloat to float

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin loading overlay class to display loading ICON and I'm using the class that provided by xamarin . The problem is that when I make the class and paste the codes inside it, Visual studio display errors at the following lines :

```
activitySpinner.Frame = new RectangleF(
centerX - (activitySpinner.Frame.Width / 2),
centerY - activitySpinner.Frame.Height - 20,
activitySpinner.Frame.Width,
activitySpinner.Frame.Height);
```

which says this "cannot convert from 'System.nfloat' to 'float'".The error is from the arguments of RectangleF  .
How should I fix this ?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing rectangle types, System.Drawing.RectangleF vs [CoreGraphics.CGRect](http://docs2.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGRect/), thus mixing native iOS 64-bit floats and managed floats (double).

Change your RectangleF to a CGRect and things will be all good:

```
var activitySpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
activitySpinner.Frame = new CGRect ( 
   centerX - (activitySpinner.Frame.Width / 2) ,
   centerY - activitySpinner.Frame.Height - 20 ,
   activitySpinner.Frame.Width,
   activitySpinner.Frame.Height);
```